I've tried writing a trigger for this, but I'm having trouble. Please help me out
Trigger RatingPopulate on Opportunity(after insert, after update)
{
    OpportunityHandler.RatingPop(trigger.new);
} 

Apex Handler
public class OpportunityHandler {
    
    public static void RatingPop(List<Opportunity> oppList, Map<Id, Opportunity> OppMap)
    {
        set<id> accountIds = new set<id>();
        for(Opportunity op : oppList)
        {
            if(op.StageName == 'Closed Won')
            {
                accountIds.add(op.AccountId);
            }
        }
        
        for(AggregateResult ar : [SELECT AccountId, SUM(Amount) totalRevenue FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId IN :accountIds AND StageName = 'Closed Won' GROUP BY AccountId])
        {
            Id accountId = (Id)ar.get('AccountId');
            Decimal AnnualRevenue = (Decimal)ar.get('totalRevenue');
            String rating = calculateRating(totalRevenue);
            accountsToUpdate.put(accountId, new Account(Id = accountId, Rating = rating));
        }

        if(!accountsToUpdate.isEmpty())
        {
            update accountsToUpdate;
        }
    }

    private String calculateRating(Decimal totalRevenue) 
    {
        if (totalRevenue >= 100000)
            return 'Hot';
        else if (totalRevenue >= 50000 && totalRevenue < 100000) 
        {
            return 'Warm';
        }
        else 
        {
            return 'Cold';
        }
    }
}


calculateRating() is simple enough that you should probably just make it a formula field. There's also some code style things that could be addressed (no need to check if a collection is empty before performing DML, be consistent with whitespace, always use braces for if/else even if it's just one line, method and variable names should start with a lowercase letter).

Aside from that, what's the actual problem you're running into here? I can see one particular issue where a variable wasn't declared, but you should [edit] your question to tell us what the issue is. If you're getting an error message, you should copy/paste it into your question (do not put it in a comment) verbatim. If you try to make it shorter, you're going to cut out important information.

Also, did you use chatGPT (or another, similar LLM "A.I.") to generate this code? If so, then this is a prime example of why you shouldn't blindly trust it, and why it's not appropriate for beginners. You're going to have a hard time making any real progress with Salesforce if you lean on the crutch of A.I. too much. If that is the case, then https://trailhead.salesforce.com is going to be a better resource to help get you started.

First of all, this should probably be a rollup summary and a record-triggered flow. You don't need any code at all in modern Salesforce.
As far as doing this in a trigger, you have a number of problems with your code. The main one being that the trigger is only passing in Trigger.new, while the function is expecting Trigger.new and Trigger.oldMap.
This trigger also doesn't account for what happens if a user deletes or undeletes an opportunity.
Instead, change your trigger to:
trigger RatingPopulate on Opportunity(
  after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete
) {
    OpportunityHandler.RatingPop(Trigger.new, Trigger.old);
} 

And then change your handler to accept these parameters, and we can also clean up your trigger logic:
public class OpportunityHandler {
  public static void RatingPop(Opportunity[] triggerNew, Opportunity[] triggerOld) {
    Opportunity[] empty = new Opportunity[0];
    Map<Id, Account> accounts = new Map<Id, Account>();
    Map<Id, Account> updates = new Map<Id, Account>();
    for(Opportunity[] recordList: new List<List<opportunity>> { triggerOld, triggerNew}){
      for(Opportunity record: recordList ?? empty) {
        accounts.put(record.AccountId, null);
        updates.put(record.AccountId, new Account(Id=record.AccountId, Rating='Cold'));
      }
    }
    accounts.remove(null);
    updates.remove(null);
    accounts.putAll([SELECT Rating FROM Account WHERE Id = :accounts.keySet()]);
    for(AggregateResult result: [SELECT AccountId Id, SUM(Amount) sum FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :accounts.keySet() AND IsWon = true GROUP BY AccountId]) {
      updates.get((Id)result.get('Id')).Rating = calculateRating((Decimal)result.get('sum'));
    }
    for(Id accountId: accounts.keySet()) {
      if(accounts.get(accountId).Rating == updates.get(accountId).Rating) {
        updates.remove(accountId);
      }
    }
    update updates.values();
  }

  String calculateRating(Decimal totalRevenue) {
    if (totalRevenue >= 100000) {
      return 'Hot';
    }
    if (totalRevenue >= 50000) {
      return 'Warm';
    }
    return 'Cold';
  }
}

